# How to check if values in array is present in object key of object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I want to check if values in one array is present in object key of object array.
For example: arr = ["id1", "id2"]

objectArr = [{id: "id1"}]

I want to throw not found error in this case when id2 is not present in id of object array.
Help of any kind would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you interested in typescript solution? Where TS will throw a type error?

Answer (score 2):

You can use filter and some for that:

```
var objectArr = [{id: "id1"}, {id: "id3"}]
var arr1 = ["id1", "id2"];
const notFounds = arr1.filter(el => !objectArr.some(obj => obj.id === el ));
console.log(notFounds); // ["id2"]
```

JS Array some:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

JS Array filter:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
var arr = ["id1", "id2", "id3", "id4"];
var n = arr.includes("id2"); //true
```

For an array of objects. If the id is unique in the array

```
var arr = [{id:"id1"},{id:"id2"},{id:"id3"},{id:"id4"}]
const found = arr.some(el => el.id === "id3") // true
```

Answer (score 0):

If You iterate over `objectArr`, You can get object fields in form of array with: `Object.entries(your_object)`.

```js
for (const obj of objectArr) {
    for (const item of Object.entries(obj)) {
        // where item is field in object
        // now You can compare if item is in [id1,id2]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: `ran.t` has a better answer that keeps track of which ids are not found.

It sounds like what you're looking for is [.every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method. Which will allow you can check each element in the array passes a given condition.

You can combine this with the [.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method to check at least one object in the `objectArr` has `id` equal to your element

```
const allElementsFound = ["id1", "id2"].every(el => objectArr.some(obj => obj.id === el))
if(!allElementsFound) {
    // throw error 
}
```